# i18next - Random language change after a few page navigations

Tags: next.js, middleware, i18next

I'm using next 13.5 (app directory) and i18next 15.0.
The problem is i want to implement a language switch button as above:

```
'use client';
// import i18next from 'i18next';
// import { t } from 'i18next';
import { usePathname, useRouter } from 'next/navigation';
// import { setCookie } from 'nookies';
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

export default function LanguageSwitch({ lang }: { lang: string }) {
  const pathName = usePathname();
  const router = useRouter();

  const [language, setLanguage] = useState(lang);
  useEffect(() => {
    // i18next.changeLanguage(language);
    const newPath = pathName?.replace(/^\/(en|fa)/, `/${language}`);
    if (!newPath) {
      return;
    }
    router.push(newPath);
  }, [language, pathName, router]);

  const handleClick = () => {
    setLanguage((prevLanguage) => (prevLanguage === 'en' ? 'fa' : 'en'));

    // setCookie(null, 'i18next', language === 'en' ? 'fa' : 'en', {
    //   maxAge: 30 * 24 * 60 * 60,
    //   path: '/'
    // });
    // i18next.changeLanguage(language);
  };

  return (
    <div
      className="mx-auto flex h-10 w-[12rem] md:w-[7rem] flex-shrink-0 cursor-pointer select-none items-center rounded-lg bg-white bg-opacity-50 p-1 backdrop-blur-md"
      onClick={handleClick}
    >
      <div
        className={`flex h-8 w-1/2 items-center justify-center gap-2.5 rounded-lg text-black transition-all duration-1000 ${
          language === 'en' ? 'bg-white' : ''
        }`}
      >
        EN
      </div>
      <div
        className={`flex h-8 w-1/2 items-center justify-center gap-2.5 rounded-lg text-black transition-all duration-1000 ${
          language === 'fa' ? 'bg-white' : ''
        }`}
      >
        FA
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

when i click language switch button it look to be right but after i do some page navigations, if the language is Persian it switches back to English or if it is English it switches to Persian.

Here is my middleware:

```
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server';
import acceptLanguage from 'accept-language';
import { fallbackLng, languages, cookieName } from './app/i18n/setting';

acceptLanguage.languages(languages);

export const config = {
  matcher: [
    '/((?!api|_next/static|_next/image|static|favicon.ico|sw.js|robots.txt).*)'
  ]
};

export function middleware(req: any) {
  let lng;
  if (req.cookies.has(cookieName))
    lng = acceptLanguage.get(req.cookies.get(cookieName).value);
  if (!lng) lng = acceptLanguage.get(req.headers.get('Accept-Language'));
  if (!lng) lng = fallbackLng;

  // Redirect if lng in path is not supported
  if (
    !languages.some((loc) => req.nextUrl.pathname.startsWith(`/${loc}`)) &&
    !req.nextUrl.pathname.startsWith('/_next')
  ) {
    return NextResponse.redirect(
      new URL(`/${lng}${req.nextUrl.pathname}`, req.url)
    );
  }

  if (req.headers.has('referer')) {
    const refererUrl = new URL(req.headers.get('referer'));
    const lngInReferer = languages.find((l) =>
      refererUrl.pathname.startsWith(`/${l}`)
    );
    const response = NextResponse.next();
    if (lngInReferer) response.cookies.set(cookieName, lngInReferer);
    return response;
  }

  return NextResponse.next();
}
```

i18next settings:

```
export const fallbackLng = 'en'
export const languages = [fallbackLng, 'fa']
export const defaultNS = 'translation'
export const cookieName = 'i18next'

export function getOptions (lng = fallbackLng, ns = defaultNS) {
  return {
    // debug: true,
    supportedLngs: languages,
    fallbackLng,
    lng,
    fallbackNS: defaultNS,
    defaultNS,
    ns
  }
}
```

index.ts:

```
import { createInstance } from 'i18next';
import resourcesToBackend from 'i18next-resources-to-backend';
import { initReactI18next } from 'react-i18next/initReactI18next';
import { getOptions } from './setting';

const initI18next = async (lng: any, ns: any) => {
  const i18nInstance = createInstance();
  await i18nInstance
    .use(initReactI18next)
    .use(
      resourcesToBackend(
        (language: any, namespace: any) =>
          import(`./locales/${language}/${namespace}.json`)
      )
    )
    .init(getOptions(lng, ns));
  return i18nInstance;
};

let keyPrefix: string;
export async function useTranslation(
  lng: any,
  ns: any,
  options = { keyPrefix }
) {
  const i18nextInstance = await initI18next(lng, ns);
  return {
    t: i18nextInstance.getFixedT(
      lng,
      Array.isArray(ns) ? ns[0] : ns,
      options.keyPrefix
    ),
    i18n: i18nextInstance
  };
}
```

client.ts:

```
'use client';
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import i18next from 'i18next';
import {
  initReactI18next,
  useTranslation as useTranslationOrg
} from 'react-i18next';
import { useCookies } from 'react-cookie';
import resourcesToBackend from 'i18next-resources-to-backend';
import LanguageDetector from 'i18next-browser-languagedetector';
import { getOptions, languages, cookieName } from './setting';

const runsOnServerSide = typeof window === 'undefined';

//
i18next
  .use(initReactI18next)
  .use(LanguageDetector)
  .use(
    resourcesToBackend(
      (language: any, namespace: any) =>
        import(`./locales/${language}/${namespace}.json`)
    )
  )
  .init({
    ...getOptions(),
    lng: undefined, // let detect the language on client side
    detection: {
      order: ['path', 'htmlTag', 'cookie', 'navigator']
    },
    preload: runsOnServerSide ? languages : []
  });

export function useTranslation(lng: any, ns: any, options?: any) {
  const [cookies, setCookie] = useCookies([cookieName]);
  const ret = useTranslationOrg(ns, options);
  const { i18n } = ret;
  if (runsOnServerSide && lng && i18n.resolvedLanguage !== lng) {
    i18n.changeLanguage(lng);
  } else {
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/rules-of-hooks
    const [activeLng, setActiveLng] = useState(i18n.resolvedLanguage);
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/rules-of-hooks
    useEffect(() => {
      if (activeLng === i18n.resolvedLanguage) return;
      setActiveLng(i18n.resolvedLanguage);
    }, [activeLng, i18n.resolvedLanguage]);
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/rules-of-hooks
    useEffect(() => {
      if (!lng || i18n.resolvedLanguage === lng) return;
      i18n.changeLanguage(lng);
    }, [lng, i18n]);
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/rules-of-hooks
    useEffect(() => {
      if (cookies.i18next === lng) return;
      setCookie(cookieName, lng, { path: '/' });
    }, [lng, cookies.i18next, setCookie]);
  }
  return ret;
}
```